# Can you use a variable in 'with_items' for different hosts (referencing 'defaults')?

Tags: ansible

I want to have a list of default directories needed for various database servers. Based on the hostname, I'd like to make different directories. Currently, this code fails: (ansible doesn't like the - hostname_short.stdout + "_postgres_dirs" statement)

```
---
# tasks file for postgres

- name: Get hostname
    shell: 'hostname -s'
    register: hostname_short

- name: Make directories needed by postgres (data and otherwise)
  file:
    path: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: directory
    owner: postgres
    group: postgres
  with_items:
    - hostname_short.stdout + "_postgres_dirs"

Where defaults/main.yml contains:
db01_postgres_dirs:
  - { name: "/opt/postgres" }
  - { name: "/opt/postgres/data_dir }

and then I can variablize it such that:
db02_postgres_dirs:
  - { name: "/opt/postgres13" }
  - { name: "/opt/postgres13/data_dir }
```

Such that I can iterate through all the db servers.

Or am I going about it the wrong way?

Comment: could you display the content of hostname_short.stdout?

Comment: i dont understant what you have done  hostname_short.stdout  is not a list???  could you precise with a sample what you want.. (and show the content)

Comment: @Frenchy 
- name: Get hostname
    shell: 'hostname -s'
    register: hostname_short
hostname_short becomes db01, db02, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Given the inventory

```
shell> cat hosts
db01
db02
db03
```

---

Q: ***"Use a variable in 'with_items' for different hosts."***

A: Create the variable

```yaml
    postgres_dirs:
      db01:
        - name: /opt/postgres
        - name: /opt/postgres/data_dir
      db02:
        - name: /opt/postgres13
        - name: /opt/postgres13/data_dir
      default:
        - name: /opt/postgres14
        - name: /opt/postgres14/data_dir
```

and use it in the loop. For example,

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Create dir {{ item.name }} on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      loop: "{{ postgres_dirs[inventory_hostname]|d(postgres_dirs.default) }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: Create dir /opt/postgres on db01
  msg: Create dir /opt/postgres/data_dir on db01
  msg: Create dir /opt/postgres13 on db02
  msg: Create dir /opt/postgres13/data_dir on db02
  msg: Create dir /opt/postgres14 on db03
  msg: Create dir /opt/postgres14/data_dir on db03
```

---

Comments

- Example of the complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all
  vars:
    postgres_dirs:
      db01:
        - name: /opt/postgres
        - name: /opt/postgres/data_dir
      db02:
        - name: /opt/postgres13
        - name: /opt/postgres13/data_dir
      default:
        - name: /opt/postgres14
        - name: /opt/postgres14/data_dir
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Create dir {{ item.name }} on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
      loop: "{{ postgres_dirs[inventory_hostname]|d(postgres_dirs.default) }}"
```

- You can use *loop* instead of *with_items*

Comment: This looks like something I can implement. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

`with_items` will not automatically interpret variable names, it's not the same as a `when` clause. You need to wrap your expression in template brackets. Also, you should already have the short inventory hostname in `inventory_hostname_short` if you collected Ansible facts at the start of the play:

```
- name: Make directories needed by postgres (data and otherwise)
  file:
    path: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: directory
    owner: postgres
    group: postgres
  with_items:
    - {{ inventory_hostname_short }}_postgres_dirs"
```

That being said, this still doesn't achieve what you're trying to achieve. An easier way to do this is through the use of `group` and `host` variables. Add the variables per-host to your `inventory.yml`:

```
all:
  hosts:
    db01:
      postgres_dirs:
        - { name: "/opt/postgres" }
        - { name: "/opt/postgres/data_dir }
    db02:
      postgres_dirs:
        - { name: "/opt/postgres13" }
        - { name: "/opt/postgres13/data_dir }
```

Then simply reference `postgres_dirs` in your playbook:

```
- name: Make directories needed by postgres (data and otherwise)
  file:
    path: "{{ item.name }}"
    state: directory
    owner: postgres
    group: postgres
  with_items: "{{ postgres_dirs }}"
```

Comment: A nice approach, but I'm actively trying to keep things out of the inventory file, if I can. I'll definitely give this a further look on my system though. Thanks!

Comment: Fair enough, hope you find a solution better suited for your case!